# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; right syntax to use near 'block'?

Tags: mysql

I need help with this query:

```
update ibf_posts
set post =
replace (post,
'<div><div style="background: #B7E5CE;border: 1px dotted #000; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 4px solid #429E6F; color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; margin: 8px auto 0 auto; padding: 3px;">SPOILER <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:if(parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].style.display=='block'){parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].style.display='none';this.innerHTML='--Click here to view--';}else {parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].style.display='block';this.innerHTML='--Click here to hide--';}">--Click here to view--</a></div><div style="color: #000000; background: #FAFCFE; border: 1px dotted #000; border-left: 4px solid #429E6F; border-top: 0; padding: 4px; margin: 0 auto 8px auto;display:none;">',
'[spoiler]');
```

I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'block')
{parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].style.display='none' at line 1
```

Any clue? Thanks

Comment: Escape your output before using it in a query, you have stray `'`'s in there ending the literal string.

Comment: I'm not too savvy, what should do I do in practice? thank you

Comment: If you are writing this query by hand, use `\'`, however, for dynamic values the language/interface you are constructing this in might help.

Comment: Using \' worked, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are inserting the string with `'`(single apostrophe/quote marks), you need to escape all appearances of the same inside the string.

```
update ibf_posts
set post =
replace (post,
'<div><div style="background: #B7E5CE;border: 1px dotted #000; border-bottom: 0; border-left: 4px solid #429E6F; color: #000; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px; margin: 8px auto 0 auto; padding: 3px;">SPOILER <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:if(parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(\'div\')[1].style.display==\'block\'){parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(\'div\')[1].style.display=\'none\';this.innerHTML=\'--Click here to view--\';}else {parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName(\'div\')[1].style.display='block';this.innerHTML=\'--Click here to hide--\';}">--Click here to view--</a></div><div style="color: #000000; background: #FAFCFE; border: 1px dotted #000; border-left: 4px solid #429E6F; border-top: 0; padding: 4px; margin: 0 auto 8px auto;display:none;">',
'[spoiler]');
```

The escaping is done by prepending a backslash(`\`) to the quotes.

Comment: Thank you to Wrikken and Dream Eater too, using the backslash worked :)